# firebase Authentication email and password exist but cannot be authorised

Tags: python, flask, firebase-authentication

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['POST'])
def login():
    if 'user' in session:
        return "Hi, {}".format(session['user'])

    # Attempt to get the JSON data from the request
    ref = request.get_json()  # This should be a call to the method get_json()

    # Use the data from ref if it's not None
    if ref:
        email = ref.get('email')
        password = ref.get('password')
    else:
        # Handle the error or return a response if ref is None
        return "No JSON data provided", 400
    
    try:
        auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password("112233@gmail.com", '123456')
        session['user'] = email
    except:
        return "Failed to login",401

    return "Logged in successfully",200
```

I want to use pyrebase library to interact with Firebase. I am using flask to send the request. Now i already send the email and password to the flask back-end and it receive successfully, but it cannot be authorized.

I try to add new users and copy paste the email and password, but it still not working. I even hard coded the email and password in flask, but not.

Comment: The code to sign in looks fine at first glance. Do you get any error message back from the server?